# Proper way of sculpting for smoothing bumps?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, bump

[image]

I was sculpting my model and I used dyntopo while sculpting. On skin some bumps appeared while sculpting. With "bumps" I mean the curves on the skin. You can see them especially on the legs. It looks like a skin health problem; for example, cellulite. I couldn't fix them with smooth and flatten tools. These tools only made my body parts smaller and did not effected these small bumps. Do you have any advice for fixing this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the smooth tool in the sculpting window?

Comment: yes, I already tried that but it's not helping